# Does my password is sent encrypted when I am mounting windows share on linux using CIFS?

Tags: mount, encryption, cifs

Does my password is sent encrypted when I am mounting windows share on linux using CIFS?

For mounting I'm using:

```
mount -t cifs -o username=myuser //myhost/share /mnt/winmount
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends.

I believe that the server can request that you send in plaintext.

Plaintext was the default until (Windows 2000?) and some home NAS devices etc... require you send it in plaintext (Which causes issues, as I think this is not allowed under recent versions of windows, without a registry hack).

Comment: +1 Close enough... The original LAN Man protocol allowed unencrypted passwords, but hasn't been enabled by default since Win95. NTLMv1 has serious hash issues: "Pass the Hash" and easily brute-forcable (a modern desktop can do it in hours, possibly faster). NTLMv2 isn't all that much better, using the flawed MD4 hash, but the exchange gets put through a much better Challenge-Response protocol, so it's much harder to nab credentials.